# Efficient conversion of Scala Map[String,Seq[String]] to java.util.Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, trying to integrate some existing Java code with Scala-specific functionality in the Play Framework.

```
val scalaMap = getScalaMap() // returns Map[String,Seq[String]]
```

What is a nice clean way to convert scalaMap to use Java collections?

```
val javaMap = ???  //  java.util.Map<String,List<String>>
```

It looks like I want to use JavaConversions, but I'm not sure how to chain together the nested collections. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val javaMap = scalaMap.mapValues(_.asJava).asJava
```

It does the job in two steps:

1. first converts `Map[String,Seq[String]]` to `Map[String,java.util.List[String]]`
2. then the whole map to Java `Map`: `java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[String]]`.

Comment: Thanks that works great. I knew there was some slick functional way to do this!

Comment: Even better. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `mapValues`.  Use `map`:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val javaMap = scalaMap.map { case (k,v) => (k, v.asJava) }.asJava
```

Using `mapValues` will cause the inner-Map to be re-converted every time it is accessed.

### A demonstration

A Scala Map

```
scala> val scalaMap = Map(1 -> Map('a -> "A"), 2 -> Map('b -> "B"))
```

Converting to a Java Map (but print something each time we convert the inner-Map)

```
scala> val javaMapBad = scalaMap.mapValues(v => { println("evaluating "+v); v.asJava }).asJava
evaluating Map('a -> A)
evaluating Map('b -> B)
javaMapBad: java.util.Map[Int,java.util.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String]] = {1={'a=A}, 2={'b=B}}

scala> javaMapBad.get(1)
evaluating Map('a -> A)     // Re-conversion!
res0: java.util.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String] = {'a=A}

scala> javaMapBad.get(1)
evaluating Map('a -> A)     // Re-conversion!
res1: java.util.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String] = {'a=A}
```

The right way to do it

```
scala> val javaMapGood = scalaMap.map{case (k,v) => {println("evaluating "+v); (k,v.asJava)}}.asJava
evaluating Map('a -> A)
evaluating Map('b -> B)
javaMapGood: java.util.Map[Int,java.util.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String]] = {1={'a=A}, 2={'b=B}}

scala> javaMapGood.get(1)  // no re-conversion
res6: java.util.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String] = {'a=A}

scala> javaMapGood.get(1)  // no re-conversion
res7: java.util.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String] = {'a=A}
```